# How to get back to the exact same state as before accidentally adding a LINE friend?

Tags: line

Sure, in the official LINE  help and elsewhere, there's a lot of advice about hiding, and deleting and blocking friends.

But none of that tells you how to get back to the exact same state you were in before you added them.

All the methods have some side effect leaving some permanent difference.

I want to get back to the exact same state that I was in before I accidentally added them. In other words I want their state in regards to me and my state in regards to them to be exactly like it was before I ever added them.

On Facebook, one could simply click Unfriend.

But in LINE it is much more complicated.

Comment: No, I'm not angry with them. In fact I never met them. I just added the wrong person by accident  thinking they were somebody else. Maybe one day I'll encounter them in real life so I don't want to add them to my block list because they might be a great person.

Comment: And I don't want hide them, etc.  I just want to delete them from my friend list, and then delete the chat. And then I'll be 100% back to the state I was before I met them right? I don't want to leave any residue in the LINE database saying I have any opinion pro or against them

Comment: Yes, if I simply delete them from my friend list, they're still my friend excetera excetera it's all so complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete someone from your friends list by hiding them, and then going to Settings > Friends > Hidden Friends.

Tap on the `Edit` button beside the friend you want to delete and then choose "Delete". This will delete them without blocking.

Comment: That's great! I sure wish there was some official documentation.

Comment: (I was using a worse solution: don't delete the chat, you'll need it later. Now block them. Now go to your block list in Settings, and delete them. Now back in the chat, unblock them.)